# How to get retrieve a script tag from HTML file source using TWebbrowser component?

Tags: javascript, html, delphi, twebbrowser, web-inspector

In the HTML document there is **script** tag that contains some javascript function

```
<div class="container">
<div id="container2">
    <div id="container3">      
        <script>        
            loadme ('main');
        </script>
    </div>   
</div>
```

But when I do 'Inspect Element' on browser, instead of this, appears a block of tags.

```
<div class="container">
<div id="container2">
    <div id="container3">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="contenthead">
                Some Text
            </div>
            <div class="c1">
                <div class="c2">
                    <form id="myForm">
                        <label>
                            Text
                        </label>                    
                    </form>
                    <div class="c3">                            
                        <a href="#" onclick="javascript:f1('Text', 0, 0)">
                        </a>    
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear">
                    </div>
                </div>
            ...
```

I want to get this block with my own app but I cannot. I use Delphi TWebBrowser to do this.
How can I get this HTML code using Delphi WebBrowser?

Comment: "I want to get this block with my own app but I cannot."  What prolem are you having?  When I started trying something similar, I assumed that elements generated by javascript would not be accessible via the DOM.  But that turned out to be incorrect:  If they show up in the IE Developer Tools window, they are ime accessible via the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

- Yes, obviously. because while inspecting through Firefox Firebug or Chrome Firebug or IE Firebug, you can't see the script like the one you mentioned.
- And you can see your script tag by viewing through Source Window (ctrl + u  => shortcut to open source window for Chrome and Firefox. )